# Include AlphaNumeric, but Don't Match a Particular Word

Tags: regex, scala

How can I write a `Regex` for:

> equals any upper-cased alphanumeric `[0-9A-Z]+` one or more times, but **not** equal to `FOO`?

I've seen `^` to exclude any of the following characters, such as "exclude xyz":

```
scala> val blockXYZ = """[^XYZ]+""".r
blockXYZ: scala.util.matching.Regex = [^XYZ]+

scala> "XXXX".matches(blockXYZ.toString)
res26: Boolean = false

scala> "AAA".matches(blockXYZ.toString)
res27: Boolean = true

scala> "AAAX".matches(blockXYZ.toString)
res28: Boolean = false
```

But, I'm not sure how to **not** match a whole word **and** match on alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use negative lookahead in your regex:

```
^(?!FOO$)[0-9A-Z]+$
```

`(?!FOO$)` means don't match following pattern `[0-9A-Z]+` if it is `FOO` followed by end of input.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to anubhava answer you can use another option like:

```
\bFOO\b|([0-9A-Z]+)
```

And use the capturing group to keep with the content you want

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eM7hV2/2)**